# Java Cannot generate more than one JSON text

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to generate a **json file** from my data but I end up generating only one json object before I get this exception `Java Cannot generate more than one JSON text`

This is my code:

```
     OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("new_fake_students.json",false);
        JsonGenerator g = Json.createGenerator(fos);
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            String temp = matcher.group();
            String[] values = temp.split(",");
            if(values.length>=4)
            { 
              g.writeStartObject();
              g.write("id",values[0]);
              g.write("name",values[1]+values[2]);
              g.write("major",values[3]);
              g.writeEnd();
            }
        }
  g.close();
  fos.close();
}
```

Comment: `g.writeEndObject();` instead of `g.writeEnd();`??

Comment: Hey man thanks for the fast reply, I tried that but I get "error: cannot find symbol g.writeEndObj"

Comment: I don't know why, is my jar file too old? I have javax.json-1.0.4

Comment: Are we talking about the same [JsonGenerator](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.html). If we do, isn't `writeEndObj` a bit different to `writeEndObject`?

Comment: `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator` has [`writeEndObject()`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.html#writeEndObject()), but `javax.json.stream.JsonGenerator` has [`writeEnd()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonGenerator.html#writeEnd--). So it would appear that question is using Java EE version, not Jackson version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems that you generate more than one object, are you sure you don't want to generate an array of objects? Perhaps:

```
    OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("new_fake_students.json",false);
    JsonGenerator g = Json.createGenerator(fos);
    g.writeStartArray(); // start the array
    while (matcher.find())
    {
        String temp = matcher.group();
        String[] values = temp.split(",");
        if(values.length>=4)
        { 
          g.writeStartObject();
          g.write("id",values[0]);
          g.write("name",values[1]+values[2]);
          g.write("major",values[3]);
          g.writeEndObject(); // does g.writeEnd() even exists?
        }
    }
    g.writeEndArray(); // close that array
```

Comment: Thanks man again! That's weird I see writeEndObject() everywhere but the library I have doesn't recognize it. I've javax.json-1.0.4. I guess it's an old version. Also I'm new to Json. I'm trying to generate this file to import it to Mongo. Isn't better to generate these students info as a separate objects?

Comment: @FawazAl-Turbaq It's not an old version. It's a totally different library, that just happens to use similar class and method names.

Comment: Thanks man for the clarification. Do you know a way to write json objects through a loop? My goal here to import this file to Mongodb. Is it better to write them as separate objects or enclose them in one array?  I moved my writing code to a sparate function which solved the exception problem, but still my code only write on record for some reason

Comment: @FawazAl-Turbaq "My goal here to import this file to Mongodb" Then adjust your question (or open another one) specifically for your problem with Mongodb (tagging it as such). Personally, I have  never played in the MongoDb backyard, so I'm sorry but cannot help you here.